# PHP, FTP, file upload

Tags: php, ftp

I have a `form` on my page that allows me to add new articles.There are two fields for photo upload (thumbnail and main photo) unfortunately I have a problem with uploading photos on FTP.

I get the error: ftp_put (): This is a private system - No anonymous login [file]

```
$thumbnail_img = $_FILES['a_thumbnail']['name'];
$temp_name1 = $_FILES['a_thumbnail']['tmp_name'];

$thumbnail_img = $_FILES['a_image']['name'];
$temp_name2 = $_FILES['a_image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"a_thumbnails/$thumbnail_img");
move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,"a_images/$thumbnail_img");


$destination_file1 = "/www/a_thumbnails/";
$destination_file2 = "/www/a_images/";


// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftgt_ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftgt_user_name, $ftgt_user_pass);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// upload the file
$upload1 = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file1, $temp_name1, FTP_BINARY);
$upload2 = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file2, $temp_name2, FTP_BINARY);

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

form:

```html
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
    <div class = row>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 50px; text-align: left">
                <label>Thumbnail</label>
                <input name="a_thumbnail" type="file" class="form-control" style="margin-left: -25px;!important; border: none" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 50px; text-align: left">
                <label>Photo</label>
                <input name="a_image" type="file" class="form-control" style="margin-left: -25px;!important; border: none"  required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="submit" value="SAVE" type="submit" style="width: 95%;"  class="btn btn-primary form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message stated that your FTP server requires user login. So you must have a proper [ftp_login()](https://www.php.net/ftp_login) on the connection before putting files there. And your login information is probably incorrect.

Try to test the login result before proceeding to upload. Like this:

```php
$thumbnail_img = $_FILES['a_thumbnail']['name'];
$temp_name1 = $_FILES['a_thumbnail']['tmp_name'];

$thumbnail_img = $_FILES['a_image']['name'];
$temp_name2 = $_FILES['a_image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"a_thumbnails/$thumbnail_img");
move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,"a_images/$thumbnail_img");


$destination_file1 = "/www/a_thumbnails/";
$destination_file2 = "/www/a_images/";


// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftgt_ftp_server);

// login with username and password
if (!ftp_login($conn_id, $ftgt_user_name, $ftgt_user_pass)) {
    // You'd probably want better error handling here
    exit('FTP Login Failed');
}

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// upload the file
$upload1 = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file1, $temp_name1, FTP_BINARY);
$upload2 = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file2, $temp_name2, FTP_BINARY);

ftp_close($conn_id);
```